# Подстановка HTMLElement.style

Tags: javascript

Создаю функцию для быстрого создания тега.

Выглядит примерно так.

```
function createElemenet(tag, param)
{
    var element = document.createElement(tag);

    if(param.className || param.class)
        element.className = param.className ? param.className : param.class;

    if(param.id)
        element.id = param.id;

    if(param.events)
    {
        for(action in param.events)
        {
            element.addEventListener(action, param.events[action], false);        
        }
    }

    if(param.style)
    {
        for(attribute in param.style)
        {
            element.style.attrStyle = param.style[attrStyle]; // тут не пашет
        }
    }

    return element;
}
```

когда хочу подцеплять стили, не могу подставить нужный стиль к element.style.backgroundColor (допустим так)

вызов выглядит вот так примерно

```
createElemenet('div', 
{
    id: 'test',
    class: 'test',
    style: {
        backgroundImage: '200px'
    }
})
```

вроде въезжаю, что просто строку нельзя подставить, но как правильно сделать, въехать не могу

Answer (score 0):

Слева - так же как справа.

```
    for(var attribute in param.style)
    {
        element.style[attribute] = param.style[attribute]; // тут пашет
    }
```

```js
function createElemenet(tag, param) {
  var element = document.createElement(tag);

  if (param.className || param.class)
    element.className = param.className || param.class;

  if (param.id)
    element.id = param.id;

  if (param.events) {
    for (action in param.events) {
      element.addEventListener(action, param.events[action], false);
    }
  }

  if (param.style) {
    for (var attribute in param.style) {
      element.style[attribute] = param.style[attribute];
    }
  }

  return element;
}

document.body.appendChild(createElemenet('div', {
  id: 'test1',
  className: 'block',
  style: {
    backgroundColor: 'lightgreen'
  }
}));
document.body.appendChild(createElemenet('div', {
  id: 'test2',
  class: 'block'
}));
```

```css
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: pink;
}
```